# A-Frame: Default value 'true' does not match type 'boolean' in browser.js

Tags: three.js, components, aframe

I've been fighting with this for a while. The console seems to populate with incorrect match types, when it's actually getting the right type.

```
    Default value `true` does not match type `boolean` in component `nav-panel`
    Default value `false` does not match type `boolean` in component `nav-panel` 
    Default value `0` does not match type `number` in component `nav-button`
```

It does get annoying to see this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that those defaults are string values, and they are not defined in their types per se.

When defined in the schema, if you have a number or a Boolean they cannot be wrapped in quotes `""` (If you do so, you're telling A-Frame that those are strings!)

This means:

Change "true" to true, and '0' to 0:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('nav-panel', {
 schema : {
  active: {type: "boolean", default: "true"},  
  textOffset: {type: 'number', default: '0'},

 },

}
```

Correct:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('nav-panel', {
 schema : {
  active: {type: "boolean", default: true},  
  textOffset: {type: 'number', default: 0},

 }
}
```